# Get data from relationship table suitecrm api

Tags: php, api, one-to-many, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am new to suitecrm, as far as form the documentation and some tutorials i have created a relationship between "Account" and "Purchased Service List" modules which is one-to-many relationship  now i want to retrive all purchase service for a specific account but i get empty result

```
public function getPurchasedService($accountId)
{
    $sessionId = $sessionId;
    $getRelationshipsParameters = array(
        'session' => $sessionId,
        'module_name' => 'Accounts',
        'module_id' => $accountId,
        'link_field_name' => 'accounts_service_packages_purchased_1',
        'related_module_query' => '',
        'related_fields' => array(
        ),
        'related_module_link_name_to_fields_array' => array(),
        'deleted' => '0',
        'order_by' => '',
        'offset' => 0,
        'limit' => '',
    );
    $getRelationshipsResult1 = $this->connector->request("get_relationships", $getRelationshipsParameters);
```

there are records in database but i could not retrieve am I missing something ????

Comment: Which API version and endpoint you are using?

Comment: I am using api version v4.1